# Changing form data after failed validation in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

How can I change view data after failed validation (I want to change a checkbox value while displaying validation errors to explain why you can't select it). I suppose form events doesn't help here as the validation happens in the end.

Comment: Could you add some code?

Comment: There's nothing really to add.. I just have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code snippet from the Symfony's from bootstrap layout shows how you can check whether form field is valid or not:

```
{% block form_row -%}
{% spaceless %}
    <div class="form-group{% if (not compound or force_error|default(false)) and not valid %} has-error{% endif %}">
        {{ form_label(form) }}
        <div class="{{ block('form_group_class') }}">
            {{ form_widget(form) }}
            {{ form_errors(form) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{%- endblock form_row %}
```

Look at `if (not compound or force_error|default(false)) and not valid` you can use same check in your code.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you should add boolean value to your model, add checkbox type to your FormType representing this value and set it to false when validation fails, like this:

```
$form->setData($model);
if (!$form->isValid()) {
    $model->setFlag(false);
} else {
    // save model, redirect etc
}
```

Comment: Didn't work - I think this is because the data has already been bound to the form. I tried calling setData and that only threw exception "You cannot change the data of a bound form".

Comment: Try to set it to false before you call submit (of course only in case you are redirecting user if the form is valid)

Comment: The other way is to create a new instance of a form with proper data